# Is There a good reason for not Implementing Client Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, orchardcms

i had downloaded orchard cms and was playing with it. i noticed that they have not implemented client validation for their form inputs (comments etc.). i noticed similar behavior on some other sites (big sites like google adsense form). So, is there a good reason for not implementing client validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time. Feel free to implement it and submit a patch.